# Why it doesn't work in Python regular expression

Tags: python, regex

```
str = 'an simple example'
print re.sub(r'^AN', 'A', str, re.I)
```

It was expected print `A simple example`
but, it still print `an simple example`

python version 2.7(Fedora x84_64)

Comment: Also, dont use `str` as a variable name. Its a built in type for string

Answer (score 2):

The last parameter of `re.sub` is a count of the replacements to do.
If you want to replace with options, compile the regex:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'^AN', re.IGNORECASE)
>>> my_str = 'AN simple example'
>>> r.sub('A', my_str)
'A simple example'
```

Answer (score 2):

As bereal pointed out, the third parameter is the count of replacements to do.

The whole definition of `re.sub` is

```
def sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):
```

So instead of compiling the regex, you can use

```
print re.sub(r'^AN', 'A', str, 0, re.I)
```

or with a named parameter:

```
print re.sub(r'^AN', 'A', str, flags=re.I)
```

---

BTW, `str` is already a python function (but no reserved keyword),
so redefining str could lead to strange problems.

Comment: (Just to add, flags in `re.sub` are since 2.7)

Answer (score 1):

If you want insensitive substitution use the insensitive option:

```
str = 'an simple example'
print re.sub(r'(?i)an', 'A', str)
```